# copy the values of plsql function in to a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to oracle. Is it possible to copy the values of PLSQL function in to a new table?

The function name is table(oracleerrors), i guess this is a function.

Comment: create the table and use `insert into TableName Select .... from ....`

Answer (score 1):

if the function is called using the table() function, then it's a pipelined function, which indeed returns data.
you can insert it using

```
insert into table (fields)
select fields
from table(func(params));
```